# get most frequent values in every month in 2021

Tags: sql, postgresql

Trying to get the most  frequent values in every month
from tables

inspection table :

```
CREATE TABLE inspection (lno INT,
                         idate DATE,
                         iid INT,
                         stime TIME,
                         passed INT,
                         violations VARCHAR(100),
                         check (passed = 1 or passed = 0),
                         PRIMARY KEY(lno,idate),
                         FOREIGN  key (lno) REFERENCES restaurant);
```

can be ignored - > FOREIGN  key (lno) REFERENCES restaurant)

data :

```
INSERT INTO inspection VALUES
(234,'6.1.2020' ,333, '16:00', 1 ,NULL),
(123,'7.2.2020' ,333 ,'12:15' ,0 ,'rats'),
(234, '7.2.2020', 333, '17:00', 0, 'Bugs'),
(456, '1.3.2021' ,222, '20:00' ,1,NULL),
(234, '10.3.2021', 333, '16:00', 1,NULL),
(567, '24.3.2021' ,333, '17:00' ,1,NULL),
(345, '9.4.2021' ,222, '18:00', 0, 'Rats'),
(345, '30.4.2021' ,222, '18:00' ,1,NULL),
(123,'11.5.2021', 111, '19:40', 0 ,'Mold'),
(567, '15.5.2021' ,111 ,'19:00' ,1,NULL),
(345, '17.5.2021' ,222, '19:00' ,1,NULL),
(456, '19.5.2021', 111 ,'17:00', 0 ,'Bats'),
(123, '13.6.2021' ,222, '13:00', 1,NULL),
(456, '16.6.2021' ,333 ,'21:00' ,0 ,'Mold');
```

query :

```
    SELECT date_part('month', idate) ,max(iid)
FROM inspector natural join inspection where date_part('year', idate) >=  date_part('year', current_date)
GROUP BY date_part('month', idate)
```

output:

| month | id |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 333 |
| 4 | 222 |
| 5 | 222 |
| 6 | 333 |

expected output -

| month | id |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 333 |
| 4 | 222 |
| 5 | 111 |
| 6 | 222 |
| 6 | 333 |

Comment: Are you sure this is related to jQuery?

Comment: sorry by accident

Comment: Adding a Image is a bad Idea and nobody can use it to help you. Add your sample data and your expected result.

Comment: @RonNuriel please do not post data as images. It is pretty much useless, as nobody can copy & paste data from them ;)

Comment: @RonNuriel also, are you sure you're using PostgreSQL 9.1 and 9.3? These versions are "ancient" and are no longer supported.

Comment: sorry guys its my first.. do I need to add or change more data ?

Comment: Why do you need the inspector table for this? If you really need to, would you also include its structure and sample data. Also, is it by "month" really? I mean, would you treat, say,  Feb 2020 and Feb 2021 to be both Feb discarding the year part?

Comment: @RonNuriel that's it! +1

Comment: @CetinBasoz you right my bad,  I need only the months of 2021 
I am fixing my expected output now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO you don't need the inspector table for this calculation. A query like this would do:

```
with t1(month, iid, cnt) as 
(
   select date_part('month', idate), iid, count(*) 
   from inspection
   where date_part('year', idate) = date_part('year',current_date)
   group by date_part('month', idate), iid
),
t2 (month, maxCnt) as 
(
  select month, max(cnt)
  from t1
  group by month
)
select t1.month, t1.iid 
from t1 
  inner join t2 on t1.month = t2.month and t1.cnt = t2.maxCnt
order by t1.month, t1.iid;
```

Here is [Dbfiddle demo link.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=87b798fc64e43f6b7cd86d26a772448b)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a an approach without using joins. With the assistance of `DATE_PART` and `RANK`

```sql
WITH occurrences AS (
    SELECT
         DATE_PART('MONTH',idate) as month,
         iid, 
         COUNT(iid) cnt
    FROM
         inspection
    WHERE 
         DATE_PART('YEAR',idate)=2021
    GROUP BY
         DATE_PART('MONTH',idate),
         iid
),
ranked AS (
    SELECT 
        month,
        iid,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY month ORDER BY cnt DESC) rnk
    FROM 
        occurrences
)
SELECT
    month,
    iid
FROM 
    ranked
WHERE
    rnk=1
```

[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=627322cb0afa22190f25afe011465b8e)